# iOS push notification brings back old notifications to the lock screen

Tags: ios, notifications, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, push

I use Parse to send push notifications to iOS devices. This works fine. But SOMETIMES (Here is the question mark) there is a weird behavior:

1. Send push notification to a device... I swipe/tap it on the device and everything is ok. It is no longer visible on the lock screen, but on the notification center (Pull down menu). Alright!
2. Send another push notification to this device while iPhone screen is off... Notification appears, but also the old notification appears again (Even when it is one day old) and both sounds are being played almost simultaneously.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Parse employee answered this question:

> It's rare, but can happen when an app sends a lot of similar
>   notifications to the same device. It's a known problem on our side,
>   it's on our plate to get fixed.

See here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/parse-developers/Zo3xBRLWttc